# Android AVD advice, no existing decvices?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

When I open up the AVD manager in eclipse there are no exisiting devices that I can use, Do I need to create one or should it be there automatically?

Comment: You need to create one. It should be mentioned in the AVD / SDK tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started. You need to create an AVD first, to be able to run your apps on an emulator.

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html

If you have a device, you don't need an AVD.

**Update:**

> Target: Android 4.4
>
> Memory: 512MB to start with, you can increase it if you need.
>
> SD Card: 512MB is good to test your apps.

You could give some tries, and get comfortable with how to use AVD manager. Play with it a little.

Comment: Thanks, I stumbled upon that earlier but wasnt sure. Can you advice me on the settings I should use, i.e. in terms of target,memory options, internal storage and SD card? Im only trying to get started with android development so im very new!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, what device should i select?

Comment: Depends on you requirement. To start off, try the Nexus 4 config.